# Frame.GoBack(NavigationTransitionInfo) callback

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I want to scroll down to bottom of a GridView when navigating back from another page.To be more specific exactly when Frame.GoBack(NavigationTransitionInfo) ends, so the scrolling would be visible.
There is a callback or some way to notify when the transition ended?

Comment: Could  you tell where is  `GridView`. it is on previous page or current page?

Comment: The GridView is on the page that is navigated to after Frame.GoBack(NavigationTransitionInfo) called, and I was wondering if GoBack() has a callback or notifies when the page transition ended so I can do the scrolling right after that.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if GoBack() has a callback or notifies when the page transition ended

`GoBack` has no call back, so you can't detect transition ended with GoBack method. For your requirement, You could make custom callback method with `Action`.

#### Page1

```
public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
{
    public BlankPage1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    private static Action _callBackAction;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.GoBack();
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ContinueWith((task)=> {

            _callBackAction();
        });       
    }
    public static void CallBackMethod( Action action)
    {
        _callBackAction = action;

    }
}
```

#### Page0

```
public Page0()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    BlankPage1.CallBackMethod(() =>
    {
        //do some stuff

    });    
}
```

Comment: It looks like it enters OnNavigatedTo before the transition from GoBack ends.

Comment: I have updated the answer with custom callback method.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to find something like on iOS https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss

Comment: Sure, you could check [`OnNavigatingFrom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom?view=winrt-19041)override method.